# Shading tab seems incomplete (Blender 2.8)

Tags: shaders

I am running blender 2.8 and am in the shading tab. On the tutorials I've seen on YouTube, the background in the top 3d viewport is a shade of light gray and there always seems to be a second texture circle next to the white one.

As is seen in the image, my background is black and I only have one of the circles. Why is this happening?

[image]

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the file
[image]

PS. There are no nodes in the image because I have the camera selected, once I select the cube I get the default ones.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the shading menu, you probably have the scene World Checkbox selected[image]

If that's not the case, share your file to take a look at it

Comment: I had both unchecked. I left a link for the file, thanks.